# Vector form for Taylor series

Tags: reference-request, vector-analysis

What is the vector form of Taylor series for a vector valued function of a scalar variable $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n $? I presume it is exactly the same as the classical Taylor series but for confirmation  I have been searching the internet to no avail. Can anyone also point out a reference for the proof? I think the proof should follow from applying the classical case to each coordinate.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of proof so much as it is a matter of definition. What is a matter of proof is what you want to logically deduce from the Taylor series (e.g. convergence). Why are you interested in the Taylor series of a vector-valued real function?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean functions defined as $f:\Re^n \rightarrow \Re$?

Comment: @Theo Bendit: I am trying to prove that the unit vector along a chord PQ on a curve $r (u)$ tends to a unit vector as Q tends to P. For this purpose I need $r (u)=r (u_0)+(u-u_0)\dot r (u_0)+o (u-u_0) $.

Comment: @Pratik Apshinge: Yes. The question is as asked.

Comment: @Shahab Pratik Apshinge has reversed the $\Bbb{R}^n$ and the $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a function from $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the Taylor expansion would be exactly similar expansion for $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let the $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be equal to $f\left(x\right)=(g_1\left(x\right),...,g_n\left(x\right))$

Consider the Taylor expansion for each of the functions $g_1\left(x\right),...,g_n\left(x\right)$ around point $a$

$g_1\left(x\right)={\displaystyle g_1(a)+{\frac {g_1'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {g_1''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+{\frac {g_1'''(a)}{3!}}(x-a)^{3}+\cdots ,}$
and so on...
$g_n\left(x\right)={\displaystyle g_n(a)+{\frac {g_n'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {g_n''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+{\frac {g_n'''(a)}{3!}}(x-a)^{3}+\cdots ,}$

Now, $f\left(x\right)=(g_1\left(x\right),...,g_n\left(x\right))$
$=({\displaystyle g_1(a)+{\frac {g_1'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {g_1''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+\cdots }$,...,${\displaystyle g_n(a)+{\frac {g_n'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {g_n''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+\cdots })$
This is equal to:
$=(g_1\left(a\right),...,g_n\left(a\right))+({\frac {g_1'(a)}{1!}},...,{\frac {g_n'(a)}{1!}})(x-a)+({\frac {g_1''(a)}{2!}},...,{\frac {g_n''(a)}{2!}})(x-a)^2$...

Clearly, this is:
$f(a)+{\frac {f'(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac {f''(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^2...$,
which is the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ at the point $a$.